# Setting Interrupt Reason while interrupting a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

Thanks for all the help and support , I am facing a problem where by i have two threads one is a Timer thread , and another one is some File Reader thread. Now my main program is calling both the threads. The timer thread interrupts the main program on timeout , and the File Reader thread invokes the main thread if there are some IO errors. So now the problem steps in , the Main program has to know who has fired the interrupt , to print some interrupt status lets say. So how do i acheive this? Below are few things i dont want to use.

1. A flag which is used to set on Timeout and another flag for IO error (Because My main program is huge and has several parts and i cant do this check everywhere)
2. Each thread having a member variable set with status code , and the main program reading that on  interrupt.(I am ok with this, but i still need to maintain the thread objects to get the status , and my File Reader threads are many , so i have to iterate every thread to find the one interrupted).

I would appreciate your help on this , even some other way other than interrupts is also fine.

Comment: What do you mean by the timer thread interrupting the main program? Do you want whatever processing is going on in the main program to end? Why can't the timer or file reading thread just generate the output (or post the output to an event handling thread, if this is an event-driven program). I think we'd need more info about the program architecture to make any recommendations.

Comment: Posting the output to the Even handling thread???? Hmmm , actually im creating n number of threads to execute concurrent file operations , if i am expecting the output form each of them then i have to wait for each thread output only then i can create and trigger the next thread , so it dosent take the real advantage of mutithreading isnt it. What i need is i want to create those n threads and they should come back to me if there are any errors , I need which thread(say file name) and what error.By the way the Main program which i was refering to is the Event handling thread here.

Comment: @sameer , Signals ?? , Could you elaborate how they can be used ?

Comment: Why? How can there be a timeout reading files? This all seems excessively complex.

Comment: Duplicate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858992/how-can-i-interrupt-a-thread-future-executor-with-reason-in-java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I interrupt a thread/future/executor with reason in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858992/how-can-i-interrupt-a-thread-future-executor-with-reason-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

I do it by declaring an Exception variable, and then I rethrow the exception if the waiting thread gets an interrupt which the Exception variable is set:

```
IOException ioex;

synchronized(lockObject) {
    while( true ) {
        try {
            lockObject.wait();
        } catch( InterruptedException e ) {
            if( ioex != null ) { 
                throw ioex;
            }
        }
        ... normal handling ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But your run() method , dosent support to throw any exception , as per its declaration in Thread.run(). So how to rethrow ??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand your question. In this case, just handle the exception instead of rethrowing it. If you don't know how to handle it, just don't catch it at all. If it is the run() method of a thread, you'd better have a plan B for any exception that arises.

Comment: @Daniel , I am doing a thread[i].join and waiting for some n number of threads to complete , if any thread had any error it will interrupt me(they will call the targetThread.interrupt() method to inperrupt the calling thread ). But i have to know which thread has interrupted me to do some special processing based on the thread info.

Comment: let me post few threads where i found some suggesions , but not answers which i am looking for may be useful to understand my problem.                           http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9399744&#9399744                                                                                http://www.coderanch.com/t/233923/threads/java/Communication-between-threads

Comment: Wy don't you declare a static volatile variable of type Thread, where you store the interrupting Thread before doing the interrupt?

Comment: Yea that's a good idea , but is there any other way where I pass the thread information along with the interrupted exception I get.

Comment: No way. You cannot influence how its created.