# How can I interrupt a thread/future/executor with reason in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I would like to know why a given thread has been interrupted. Was it interrupted by me (part of my code), by other library or by any other reason?

Right now I can interrupt a Thread by

```
Thread.interrupt()
```

cancel a Future by

```
Future.cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)
```

shutdown a Executor by

```
ExecutorService.shutdown() or ExecutorService.shutdownNow()
```

but, none of them give me an option to send a reason (information why interruption was performed). In other words I cannot throw and catch InterruptedException with more detailed message or cause.

EDIT:
Based on Glains solution I've prepared a similar one but with using a Callable

```java
public class MyCallable<T> implements Callable<T> {
    private final Callable<T> callable;

    private volatile Thread thread;
    private volatile String interruptReason;

    public MyCallable(final Callable<T> callable) {
        this.callable = callable;
        this.thread = null;
    }

    @Override
    public T call() throws Exception {
        this.thread = Thread.currentThread(); // not getCurrentThread()
        try {
            return callable.call();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread is interrupted: " + this.interruptReason);
        }
    }

    public void interrupt(String interruptReason) {
        this.interruptReason = interruptReason;
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: What excactly do you want to do with the reason?

Comment: In most cases just log it. If thread was interrupted by a reason that is expected - no more action is needed, but if a thread was interrupted by any other reason then i would like to know it and log that accident

Comment: Do you have control over thread creation?

Comment: Yes, i have a full control over thread creation

Comment: The answer is NO. A thread can be interrupted, but there is no such api to get the reason. You have to look into the code for the interruption.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to write a custom API for that, as the `Thread` cannot be aborted with a specific reason. To make a `Runnable` able to be interrupted, you could create a custom interface that offers this functionality:

```
public interface Interruptable {

    default void interrupt() {
        interrupt(Reason.unknown());
    }

    void interrupt(Reason reason);
}
```

The defined reason can be anything, but the following may fit your use case:

```
public class Reason {

    public static Reason unknown() {
        return new Reason("unknown");
    }

    private final String reason;

    public Reason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }
}
```

Now, you would have to tweak your `Runnable` implementation so it can be interrupted. Please note that the following solution interrupts the thread gracefully, which means that the current iteration will finish, but a new one will not be started. If you want to truely interrupt the thread, you would need to store a reference to the thread executing the `Runnable` instances `run` method, since the `interrupt` method will not be called from the same thread. Then you can call `Thread.interrupt` on that reference.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable, Interruptable {

    private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Override
    public void interrupt(Reason reason) {
        running.set(false);
        System.out.println("Thread is interrupted: " + reason.getReason());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running.set(true);
        while (running.get()) {
            // do work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution with the flag is good if you have tasks running in a loop. Then as you said, you can prevent further iterations from running. In my case a have a long running single task which can be interrupted immediately at any time

Comment: Solution with implementing Runnable is not the best, because Runnable cannot throw an exception. Using Callable instead can fix that problem.

Comment: Then proceed as mentioned by storing a reference to the executing thread from `run`. Terminate it in the `interrupt` method. This should work with `AtomicReference` i suppose.

Comment: The `Runnable` is just an example on how to implement the interface. You may chose any class that implements `Interruptable`.